# Python Play two videos in one window

Tags: python, video

Is it possible to play two videos in one single window then generate a new video using python? i.e. I have video_1.avi and video_2.avi and want to create video_3.avi which includes 1 and 2. As this picture shows:
[image]

Any ideas and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just found out that I can firstly concatenate two frames as one image, then use cv2.VideoWriter() to write a video of these concatenated frames. If the number of frames of two videos are not equal, you can pad one video with white/black or whatever images you like. Hope this answer helps.